# Ruby Code navigation, reading tips and tools, how to locate a code in the file system, jump to and read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This post has been edited.

Considered deleting but decided otherwise since I needed this  quite badly two months ago.
Leave a comment if someone wants this deleted please.

Locating the gems in use:

```
bundle show # shows the list of gems used
bundle show sprockets-rails #shows the path for the gem
```

Available free tools:
Cscope:

- cscope: install via apt-get or dnf
- starscope :https://github.com/eapache/starscope/blob/master/doc/USER_GUIDE.md

Ctags :

- ctags: install via apt-get or dnf
- ripper-tags:https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags

Searching strings within files with a regular expression pattern:

- ack: install via apt-get or dnf
- the silver search:https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

IDEs:
Aptana studio
Netbeans
RubyMine(seems popular but it costs a bit).
Komodo
and more

debugging tool:https://github.com/pry/pry-git or ide's built-in

```
gem 'pry-rails' 
gem 'pry-doc'    
gem 'pry-byebug' 
gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
```

Popular editiors:

- vim
- sublime text
- atom

etc

Note:while vim seems the most popular, it requires learning and atom cannot handle a very large file as of now.

My personal conclusion:
Ruby, or at least ruby on rails, uses meta programming patterns heavily and there cscope or ctags do not perform well. The meta nature of the code also makes reading code as text difficult.

The real tool for ruby code reading was a debugger for me; pry-rails my case. It supports opening the current file with an editor and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `ripper-tags` with `vim`

https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags

Works just like `ctags`.

To generate tags for a project, you run

```
ripper-tags -R .
```